# integrating django-paypal

Tags: django, paypal

I am trying to integrate Django-Paypal onto a site, where once the customer makes a payment I need to send a dynamic URL from which the user can download some specific information.

I am registering all users to a URL which allows them to buy the document. The URL which can only be accessed by a registered user with a verified email ids using django-registration, allows the user to connect to paypal and make payment.

How do I capture the signal and verify which user has made the payment for which product he/she is purchased, based on this information

1) I need to know two information, which user made the payment, and for which product did he or she make the payment?

2) Only if I have these information can I send the right UR:L by email.

Any help appreciated. I am not very sure how django-signals work. What all details does payment_was_successful signal return?

I am using IPN

Comment: ramdaz, note that you can *checkmark* the answer, to indicate it's correct. This will also improve your accept-rate.

Answer (score 3):

To capture the signal, you define your function, and connect it to the signal like this:

```
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful
def my_payment_was_successful_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    pass

payment_was_successful.connect(my_payment_was_successful_handler)
```

To be able to identify the user the IPN message is about, I usually modify the paypal button to pass a field named `custom` along in the form set to the django `user.id` or some other identifier you can look up to identify your user.  The `custom` variable is sent back in the `sender` argument and you can find the user.

To find the product, the `product_name` is also sent in the `sender` to the handler listed above.  You'll probably have a model for your products, and you'll want to look them up by this product_name to send the appropriate thing in email.

Comment: Well, Thanks. This is exactly what I am trying to do.